# font face and color syntax errror

Tags: python, html

I am trying to add font face and  color and running into following error

```
#Create the body of the message
msg_body=("<HTML><head></head>"
          "<body>BCC Warning:"
          "<br>Hi All, <br>"
          "<br><br>"
          "<font face = "Arial" color="#990000" > Wiki @<a href=%s>%s</a> (listed @ go\wbit)</font> <br><br>"
          "<b>Release notes:</b> %s  <br><br>" 
          "<b>Build Combo:</b><br>%s<br><br>" 
          "<b>Loading instructions:</b><br>%s<br><br>"
          "<b>CR fixes:</b><br>%s<br><br>"
          "Thanks,<br>"
          "Build team"
          "</body></html>"
          ) % (wikiURL,wikiURL,Releasenotes,table,Load_ins,crInfo)
```

Syntax error

```
"<font face = "Arial" > Wiki @<a href=%s>%s</a> (listed @ go\wbit)</font> <br><br>"
                   ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write in below format

```
"<font face = 'Arial' > Wiki @<a href=%s>%s</a> (listed @ go\wbit)</font> <br><br>"
```

However it not recommended to use font tag anymore. Use `style='font:arial normal'` instead.

Updated syntax:

```
msg_body=("<HTML><head></head>"
          "<body>BCC Warning:"
          "<br>Hi All, <br>"
          "<br><br>"
          "<div style='font:Arial normal; color:#990000'> Wiki @<a href=%s>%s</a> (listed @ go\wbit)</div> <br><br>"
          "<b>Release notes:</b> %s  <br><br>" 
          "<b>Build Combo:</b><br>%s<br><br>" 
          "<b>Loading instructions:</b><br>%s<br><br>"
          "<b>CR fixes:</b><br>%s<br><br>"
          "Thanks,<br>"
          "Build team"
          "</body></html>"
          ) % (wikiURL,wikiURL,Releasenotes,table,Load_ins,crInfo)
```

Comment: Use style='font:arial normal; color:red;'. Check main answer for updated response.

Comment: `font: arial normal` is incorrect CSS and gets ignored by (conforming) browsers; the W3C CSS Validator currently has a bug that makes it pass this construct, but it’s still incorrect (and fails to do what you expect it to do).

Answer (score 0):

Add slashes to double quote within double quote string OR you can use single quote instead

```
"<font face = \"Arial\" style='color:green'> Wiki @<a href=%s>%s</a> (listed @ go\wbit)</font> <br><br>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use "\" to skip the in-quotation mark.

```
"<font face = \"Arial\" >"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is to omit the quotation marks that cause the error, writing

```
      "<font face = Arial color=#990000 > Wiki @<a href=%s>%s</a> (listed @ go\wbit)</font> <br><br>
```

Those quotes aren’t needed in HTML. Technically, by HTML 4.01 spec, quotation marks are required around the value `#9900000`, but browsers don’t require them (and neither do HTML5 drafts). Besides, the markup isn’t valid anyway; the `title` element is missing.